# Android: drawing on views canvas doesn't work

Tags: android, canvas, drawing

I'm tryin to draw a shape on a canvas under all buttons.
Here's the code:

> ```
> Paint paint = new Paint();
> paint.setColor(R.color.Kolor);
>
> View view; 
> LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)
> getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE); 
> view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.menu_glowne, null);
>
> Canvas can = new Canvas(Bitmap.createBitmap(300, 300, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888));
> can.drawRect(0, 0, 200, 200, paint);
>
> setContentView(view);
>
> view.draw(can);
> ```

Don't know why I'm still getting the layout without anything drawn underneath.
Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong?

Thanx in advance!

Comment: Can you show us a snapshot of what  u are trying to do.?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your example you are drawing the view on your canvas rather than on canvas of the view.
You should use a simple approach, don't inflate your layout but load it normally, then find the root container and set its background. Something like this:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    Paint paint = new Paint();
    paint.setColor(Color.MAGENTA);
    Bitmap bgr = Bitmap.createBitmap(480, 800, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888); 
    Canvas can = new Canvas(bgr);  
    can.drawRect(50, 50, 200, 200, paint);  
    LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.ll); 
    ll.setBackgroundDrawable(new BitmapDrawable(bgr));    

}
```

main layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
    android:id="@+id/ll">
<TextView  
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:text="@string/hello"
    />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I did like you said and it still doesn't work. I even tried inflatin a view, changing its background (and Layouts background) and setContentView again and nothing. Can't even set background color. Any change in XML declaration works fine. Any odeas what's wrong?

Comment: Check my edit, it all works perfectly. You need to import the classes which are underlined by red.

Comment: My fault... You were right! I messed up loading color from resources and ended up drawing black rectangle on black background :|

Answer (score 0):

You don't draw this way in android. Everything happens through a method override (onDraw). Follow this tutorial to get started : 
http://www.helloandroid.com/tutorials/how-use-canvas-your-android-apps-part-1

Regards,
 Stéphane